# Enviar varios valores desde la propiedad data de $.ajax (jquery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

mi consulta se refiere a que necesito enviar varios datos desde una función js a el php que los procesa. Mi función js:

```
var old_idcategoria;
var old_nombre;
var old_descripcion;

function guardaryeditar(e)
{
     var formData = new FormData($("#formulario")[0]);
     $.ajax({
        url: "../ajax/categoria.php?op=guardaryeditar",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData, 
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

        success: function (datos)
        {
            //datos imprime el resultado de la función guardaryeditar
            bootbox.alert(datos);
            mostrarForm(false);
            tabla.ajax.reload();
        }

    });
}
```

Yo necesito agregar a la propiedad data las tres variables que están afuera de la función para procesarlas desde el php:

```
$old_idcategoria = isset($_POST["old_idcategoria"]) ? limpiarCadena($_POST["old_idcategoria"]) : "";
```

¿Puedo enviar más valores en la propiedad data aparte de los que estoy enviando (datos del formulario)?

Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Puedes enviar muchos datos. Sólo necesitas leerlos para pasarlos en **data** y no solamente los de form puedes recoger toda clase de atributos de los elementos en la página y enviarlos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes incluir variables adicionales directamente en el `form` como valores `hidden`. Estos se incluiran en `formData` automaticamente.

```
<form id="formulario" >
  <input type="hidden" name="old_idcategoria" value="<?=$old_id_categoria?>" >
  ...
</form>
```

La otra forma es usando `FormData.set(name, value)` para agregarlas en javascript antes de enviar el POST.

```
var formData = new FormData($("#formulario")[0]);
formData.set('old_idcategoria','<?=$old_id_categoria?>');
```